# Интервал между определенными датами

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет!

Предмет: 
Базовая стоимость доставки груза из точки А в точку Б стоит 1000р, но она меняется в зависимости от сезона. Зимой коэффициент х2, Осенью 1.5...
В бд хранятся определенные интервалы, определяющие эти "условные" сезоны (таблица схематично).

 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача: 
На момент формирования заказа нужно проверять попадает ли время доставки в определенный интервал, ну и брать оттуда коэффициент.

Вопрос:
Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать, а конкретно как лучше хранить эти интервалы в бд. 
У меня из идей только crontime - `*,*,1,11,*`. Плюс такого подхода в том, что laravel из коробки может такой формат валидировать, но минус в том как его парсить.

Comment: Храните дату начала и дату окончания в формате `timestamp`. Вычислять попадает ли текущая дата в этот интервал можно будет прямо  в `SQL-запросе`.

Comment: Так тут именно "сезон", это не конкретные даты.
Если я напишу, к примеру, 10.10.2020 (или ее эквивалент в ts), то на следующий год она не будет актуальна.

Comment: Каждого 31.12 23:59:59 обновляете год в датах на следующий, делов-то

Comment: Возможно, так действительно проще. Благодарю.